# SQL Server : aggregating multiple measures columns into 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, unpivot

I'm a SQL novice and tried my best to search for this topic before asking.

I have data in this format:

[image: Current State Format]

I need in this format:

[image: Need in this format]

I realize this is something probably very easy, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll want to look into `unpivot` and/or `cross apply`

Comment: using SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

You can use `APPLY` if you are working with `SQL Server` :

```
SELECT t.year, tt.Months, tt.Amount
FROM TABLE t CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES (1, 'January', [Month1]), 
              (2, 'February', [Month2]), 
               . . .  
     ) tt(seq, Months, Amount)
ORDER BY tt.seq, t.year;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this on SQL SERVER:

```
CREATE TABLE TestPvt (Year varchar(32), January int, february int,  
    March int);  
GO  
INSERT INTO TestPvt VALUES ('Actual 2019',700,220,456);  
INSERT INTO TestPvt VALUES ('Budget 2019',200,752,500);  

SELECT Year, Month, Amount  
FROM   
   (SELECT Year, January, february, March  
   FROM TestPvt) p  
UNPIVOT  
   (Amount FOR Month IN   
      (January, february, March)  
)AS unpvt;
```

The result is:

```
Year    Month   Amount
Actual 2019 January 700
Actual 2019 february    220
Actual 2019 March   456
Budget 2019 January 200
Budget 2019 february    752
Budget 2019 March   500
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:
Taking the columns you provide i made this SQL, i hope this helps!
Just change the table for the original

```
SELECT Year, 
case when Month = 'Month1' then 'January'
    when Month = 'Month2' then 'February'
    when Month = 'Month3' then 'March' 
    else '' end as Month,
    Amount  
FROM   
   (SELECT Year, Month1, Month2, Month3  
   FROM  [dbo].[ExampleMonths]) tb1  
    UNPIVOT  
   (Amount for Month IN   
      (tb1.Month1, tb1.Month2, tb1.Month3)      
    ) AS uNp
```

[image]